# Xbox360's power light turns red and won't display anything

Tags: xbox-360

First when I would go to turn the Xbox on the light was just a single red dot. I couldn't connect the controller, the tray wouldn't open, and nothing was being displayed on the screen. I unplugged everything and in the process noticed the power adapter light wasn't on so I switched out the cord that connects to the outlet with a new one and the adapter was working again, I turned the Xbox on again and this time the light went on green and I could open the disc tray, but the controller and display were still not working properly. The light would then switch back to red after a minute or so. I also tried using another HDMI and monitor to no avail.

Is there still something wrong with the adapter or is my Xbox toast?

Comment: The best way to check this, if you can, is to try a different adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One red light could mean an issue with your power supply, as you've already guessed, or a number of other issues, as noted [here](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/console/flashing-lights-solution), in the trouble-shooting section for the Xbox 360. If any of the steps require a piece of hardware you don't have, you could try taking your console to a game store, preferably a smaller mom and pop type store, (they might be more accommodating) and asking them to plug it in for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the original problem was, but after 2 months I tried fiddling with the Xbox again. I used a pipe cleaner and blocked the fan while the Xbox was on, after it overheated and reset it is now working fine.