# How to solve red light indicator on Xbox-360?

Tags: xbox-360

After 25-30 minutes of game playing on Xbox-360, the game freezes and red dot light appears on my Xbox-360 in the place of green indicator power light. And then after 30 minutes I turn on my Xbox-360 again and it works fine for the next 30 minutes.

Is this some sort of hardware failure?

Comment: Possibly related to this issue: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321747/xbox360s-power-light-turns-red-and-wont-display-anything

Comment: How's airflow around your Xbox?  Do you have a lot of stuff around/on top of the Xbox that might be inhibiting air flow and therefore affecting its ability to keep cool?

Comment: Have you used compressed air to clean out your 360?

Comment: How many red lights are there?

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the (in)famous Red Ring of Death. This is almost always caused by overheating. Simply cleaning out all of the air vents, fan, and so on with some compressed air should resolve the issue. Note that the 360 works best when not in an enclosed space, like some entertainment stands have (e.g. a glass door). There needs to be good air flow around the entire system for it to avoid overheating.

If you cleaned out all the dust and other obstructions, but still experience this problem, you can fix it by increasing the thermal dissipation by using a simple trick that's been circulated on youtube involving [pennies, electrical tape, and a T9 screwdriver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsz0lNJ6JrQ), or by using a [towel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgO0BdHMZdc). Alternatively, if you don't feel like using "hacks," you can get a [RROD kit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Xbox+360+Red+Ring+of+Death+Fix+Kit/3550) that will allow you to fix the problem permanently. Finally, you might just try to find a service that will fix it for you. For example, near where I live, there's a game repair shop that can fix issues like this for a nominal fee.

Comment: I'd like to recommend ***against*** using a towel. It works by overheating the console to the point where contacts melt. If you're lucky, contacts that aren't connected well enough will connect better after hardening again. But you're actually far more likely to make things worse than they already are. It also voids your warranty (if you still have it).

Comment: @Nolonar I agree that I wouldn't use the towel method, either. I don't know that there's a single 360 in the world still under warranty anyways. Still, some people might look at the towel method as an acceptable risk/benefit cost, and some might not. I'd prefer to use a targeted method, like using an actual RROD kit, that has a virtually guaranteed chance of success.

Comment: ![this is how it looks, i think it's called red dot of death](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1xia.png)

Well i have cleared all the dust but nothing is happening problem still same, it's jtagged , the one thing i have noticed that during startup it gives many beeps like 4,5 .. After that it starts, and I noticed a blue light inside the xbox at the place of cd rom sensor, so Is there any problem with my cd rom? Although i play games with my usb, .. Those beeps are really suspicious and I think it's because some sort of hardware failure.. Plz help

Comment: @OmerKhan Beeps change the situation a bit. I don't think that a drive failure would cause the system to turn off. Maybe the PSU is having issues? At this point, you might need you need an expert to look at it. I've never seen a problem like that before.